# How to compute random walk between all pairs of nodes in graph?

Tags: r

I have a graph with 15000 nodes. I would like to compute random walk between all pairs of node in it and put in it a matrix.
I looked at igraph package in R

```
random_walk(graph, start, steps, mode = c("out", "in", "all"),
  stuck = c("return", "error"))
```

and it need to specify the start node and number of the nodes in the graph. 
I was looking a computationally efficient way to compute random walk for all possible start node of the graph.
Would  someone can help me by that ?

Here is how my graph looks like:

```
1002 DHX8   SRPK1 0.5791602
1003 DHX8  CRNKL1 0.6729812
1004 DHX8   SRPK2 0.5791602
1005 DHX8    SNW1 0.8772539
1006 DHX8  SNRPD2 0.8772539

1007 DHX8 PRPF38A 0.5110222
1008 DHX8  NOTCH1 0.6168687
1009 DHX8    TAF9 0.6729812
1010 DHX8   CDC40 0.8772539
3477 SMAD4 SMURF1 0.6168687
3478 SMAD4   RAC2 0.6392732
3479 SMAD4   DAXX 0.4907872
3480 SMAD4  KPNB1 0.6168687
3481 SMAD4    HGS 0.4288047
3482 SMAD4  NAT8B 0.8772539
3483 SMAD4     AR 0.4745135
3484 SMAD4  ILKAP 0.6608392
3485 SMAD4   SKIL 0.2383471
3486 SMAD4  USP15 0.4288047
3487 SMAD4  DACH1 0.4745135
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Could you clarify: are you looking to find a random walk distance between all pairs of nodes or do you want to compute a random walk for each node and report the distance bewteen the node found? 2) Are considering this graph directed or undirected. 3) If you are looking for all pair-wise distances how would expected unconnected nodes to be reported?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how long it will take to run since you have not provided any data, but you can use the `purrr` package to loop over each of the nodes. This will output a list of the outputs with each element of the list being a single output of the `random_walk` function.

```
output <- purrr::map(
  .x = 1:15000,
  .f = function(x){
    random_walk(graph, start = x, steps = 1000, 
                mode = "all", stuck = "return")
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks, well, my graph is weight and at the end, I need to have matrix which element i,j of it shows the random walk distance between node i,j. would you like to complete it and get the 50 + ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "my graph is weight". Also I am not too familiar with this type of graph and am not entirely sure what i and j represent in this context. sorry

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you're looking for, along with how   the outputs are to be computed. Forgive my lack of domain knowledge, but how would one computer a random walk by hand for a small graph?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that hard to implement with some base functions, assuming I am thinking about the question correctly:

```
#making the graph
m1<-sample(LETTERS, 15000, replace = T)
m2<-sample(LETTERS, 15000, replace = T)
w<-runif(15000, .1, 3)

graph<-data.frame(m1, m2, w, stringsAsFactors = F)
graph<-graph[graph$m1 != graph$m2,]

nodes<-list()

#parse the structure
for(node in unique(graph$m1)){
  temp <-list(target = c(), weight = c())
  df <-graph[graph$m1 == node,]

  if(nrow(df) == 0){
    next
  }

  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    temp$target<-c(temp$target, df[i,]$m2)
    temp$weight<-c(temp$weight, df[i,]$w)
   }

  nodes[[node]]<-temp
}
```

Now Just make a function to do the walk:

```
#Performs a single random walk
randomWalk<-function(nodes, start = 'A', steps = 5){
  step = 0:steps
  target = c(start)
  weight = c(0)

  if(!start %in% names(nodes)){
    return(paste(start, "not in list of nodes"))
    }

  for(i in 1:steps){

  options<-nodes[[start]]$target

  if(length(options) < 1){
    break
    }

  option_weights<-nodes[[start]]$weight

  rs<-sample(1:length(options), 1)
  target<-c(target, options[rs])
  weight<-c(weight, option_weights[rs])

  start<-options[rs]

  }

 return(data.frame(step, target, weight))
 }

#Testing
randomWalk(nodes, 'x', 20)
randomWalk(nodes, "X", 20)
```

A function to loop through them is simple enough.

```
many_walks<-function(nodes, steps){
  walks<-list()

  for(st in names(nodes)){
    walks[[st]]<-randomWalk(nodes, st, steps)
   }
  return(walks)
}
```

Not too slow, but depends on the number of nodes you have.

```
many_walks(nodes, 50)
```